# Count what is the maximum value in each row and divide each cell by this number (in R)

Tags: r

I would like to count what is the maximum value in each row and divide every cell by this number
Please see an example below.

```
    col1 col2 
row1 3   5
row2 4  10
row3 3  20

calculation

     col1 col2
row1 3/5  5/5
row2 4/10 10/10
row3 3/20 20/20

output

     col1 col2
row1 0.6  1
row2 0.4  1
row3 0.15 1
```

Comment: Maybe `apply(x, 1, function(x) x/max(x))` ?

Comment: This function flips columns and rows. Do you know what to do to keep rows as rows and columns as columns?

Comment: `t(apply(x, 1, function(x) x/max(x)))`

Comment: Another option: `df / do.call(pmax, df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more synthetic way using `base`

```
col1 <- c(3,4,3)
col2 <- c(5,10,20)
df <- data.frame(col1,col2) 
result <- t(apply(df,1, function(x) x/max(x)))
> result
col1 col2
[1,] 0.60    1
[2,] 0.40    1
[3,] 0.15    1
```

Basically you need to apply the function `x/max(x)` to the rows of `df` which means you need to use `1` in the `margin` parameter of `apply` and then `t` to transpose.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with the `tidyverse`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
          col1 = c(3L, 4L, 3L),
          col2 = c(5L, 10L, 20L)
)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(max_num=max(c_across(cols=everything()))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = starts_with("col"), .fns=function(x) x/max_num))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>    col1  col2 max_num
#>   <dbl> <dbl>   <int>
#> 1  0.6      1       5
#> 2  0.4      1      10
#> 3  0.15     1      20
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>